# Mapear classe com json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

Existe alguma maneira de mapear o nome das propriedades de uma classe sem utilizar a *annotation* `JsonProperty` do *Json.NET*?

A seguinte estrutura mostra duas classes que herdam da classe Bar. Contudo, o nome *json* da propriedade da classe pai (Bar) deveria ser diferente na serialização das duas classes filhas.

```
public class Bar
{
    [JsonProperty("property_1")]
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
}

public class Foo : Bar
{
    [JsonProperty("property_2")]
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
}

public class FooBar : Bar
{
    [JsonProperty("property_3")]
    public string Property3 {get;set;}
}
```

Além disso, gostaria de evitar colocar annotations nas entidades de domínio da aplicação, realizando o mapeamento para json em um projeto a parte.

Comment: Já tentou tornar a `Property1` como `virtual` e mudar a anotação com overload da propriedade?

Answer (score 1):

Vinicius, como alternativa, você pode utilizar o Attributo `[DataContract]`e `[DataMember]` no lugar do `[JsonObject]` e `[JsonProperty]` respectivamente.

Mas ao faze-lo, terá de colocar `[DataMember]` em todas as propriedades que deseja serializar, uma vez que omitir o `[DataMember]` será o mesmo de adicionar um `[JsonIgnore]`.

Esta abordagem pode ser bastante util, se quiser expor os seus objetos através de uma `WebAPI` ou `WCF`, inclusive o `[DataMember]` possui o atributo `EmitDefaultValue`, caso setado para false, ele não irá serializar propriedades enquanto estiverem com o valor `default`.

Mas se que saber se tem como declarar o nome da propriedade de uma forma que não utilize `Attributes`, infelizmente você terá de escrever o seu proprio [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm), então talvez não seja viavel.

se preferir, pode adicionar os atributos em outras classe, para faze-lo utilize o Attributo `[MetadataType]`, isto abordagem é especialmente util para manter atributos em classes geradas de forma automatica, então vamos pegar como base a seguinte classe:

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    public string Property3 {get; set;}
}
```

então teriamos de fazer o seguinte em um arquivo separado:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyMetaData))]
public partial class MyClass
{

}

public class MyMetaData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "property_1")]
    public string Property1 {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "property_2")]
    public string Property2 {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "property_3")]
    public string Property3 {get; set;}
}
```

apesar de acreditar que a resposta acima não tenha resolvido o seu problema, espero ter lhe dado um norte.

Comment: tentei utilizar o JsonConverter mas ao chamar uma biblioteca externa (NEST) que também usa o Json.NET, ele ignorou o converter. Estou testando com DataContract e DataMember, dando override nas propriedades que preciso mudar o nome. Não é o que eu desejava, porque estou usando DDD e queria passar esta configuração pra camada de infraestrutura, e não na de domínio, mas deve servir no momento